# How to use python script in django?

Tags: python, django, csv

I'd like to use this at my homepage in django project(python 3.7.2 and django 2.1.7 installed). Input file will be uploaded different way. I only want to know how to use/where to paste script like this. Thanks for help!

```
 from csv import reader, writer
    name = input("Please input your file's name.")
    with open(name) as file:
        csv_reader = reader(file)
        search_input = input("Search by word?")        
        for search in csv_reader:
            for rows in search:
                if search_input == rows:
                    print(search)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reading it from local memory you can grab a file from request it will be in memory then you can pass in memory file to `csv.reader` it can read it.

You should create a form first like this or you can use django-form in template:

```
<form action="/your/url/here" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
<br>
 <label>Word</label>
    <input name="word" type="text" />
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

In your view you can do

```
import csv
def myview(request):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(request.FILES['uploadedfile']) #to read in memory file
    search=request.POST.get("word")
    #your stuff here
    for search in csv_reader:
            for rows in search:
                if search_input == rows:
                    #you can return HttpResponse
                    return HttpRespose(search)
    #or return something like this if not found
    return HttpResponse("Not found")
```